# Search for an object in an array Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a model called department. I have an array with rooms and every room has a patient (with a patientnr).

I want to get the patient with the patientnr that is equal to the request id. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
var department = mongoose.model('department', {
    departmentName: String,
    rooms: [
        {
            roomNumber: String,
            width: Number,
            height: Number,
            posX: Number,
            posY: Number,
            sanitary: Boolean,
            childcareArea: Boolean,
            lounge: Boolean,
            patient: {
                patientnr: Number,
                firstname: String,
                lastname: String,
                reasonOfHospitalization: String,
                dateOfHospitalization: Date,
                expectedDateOfDischarge: Date,
                vegetarian: Boolean,
                needsHelp: Boolean,
                comments: String,
                department: String,
                roomNumber: String,
                nextTreatment: {
                    type: String,
                    shortDescription: String,
                    timestamp: Date
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

//get patient with id
app.get('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
    department.find({"patient": {$all :[60022]}}, function (err, patient) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(patient);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to be able to provide you some assistance, it would be helpful if provide what attempts you have made to find a solution. Also, you may want to [Read This Help Article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** in your projection as follows:

```
//get patient with id
app.get('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
    department.findOne(
        { "rooms.patient.patientnr": parseInt(req.params.id) }, 
        { 
            "rooms": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "patient.patientnr": parseInt(req.params.id)
                }
            }
        },
        function (err, dept) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            var patient = dept.rooms[0].patient;
            res.json(patient);
        }
    );
});
```

or the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

```
//get patient with id
app.get('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
    department.findOne(
        { "rooms.patient.patientnr": parseInt(req.params.id) }, 
        { "rooms.$": 1 },
        function (err, dept) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            var patient = dept.rooms[0].patient;
            res.json(patient);
        }
    );
});
```

or using the aggregation framework:

```
//get patient with id
app.get('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
    department.aggregate(
        [
            { "$match": { "rooms.patient.patientnr": parseInt(req.params.id) } },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "room": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                            {
                                "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$rooms",
                                    "as": "room",
                                    "cond": {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            "$$room.patient.patientnr", 
                                            parseInt(req.params.id)
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],  function (err, results) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            var patient = results[0].room.patient;
            res.json(patient);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I have now the patient, but it would be very nice if I would get the treatment of that patients as well. Now I get all the patient attributes except for treatment.

Comment: I get the treatments as well when I use the aggregation framework, thanks!

Comment: Would you mind checking this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509547/post-an-object-to-mongodb-mongoose
basically what needs to happen is that this patient info gets edited and posted back to the mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
//get patient with id
app.get('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    department.find({"rooms.patient.patientnr": id}, function (err, patient) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(patient);
    });
});
```

Comment: Almost, this gives back the whole department with my rooms & patients.
But I need only the patient back.

Comment: Oh. Do you want to return patient object only?

Comment: Yes, if that is possible :)

Comment: You can use unwind then

Comment: Well, i guess @chridam had answered it for you. Just refer to that.